# How does a Blu-ray player know where I stopped a movie?

Tags: blu-ray

I played a Blu-ray movie disk the other night on the Blu-ray player in my basement.  I stopped the movie about halfway through the end credits.  A few days later when I put the disk in my living room Blu-ray player - a different player that is not connected in any way to the basement player - the movie started up from the exact point in the end credits where I stopped it on the basement player.  How is this possible?  Do the players write some kind of data on the disk?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible thanks to BD-J(ava), which actually does allow players to store this information on the disc. A lot more is possible as well, mainly in the direction of interactive content. Here's the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BD-J).

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert on Blu-Ray, but I am a programmer and I know they probably have some kind of file system on the blu-ray system that stores where the movie last left off at. I doubt they wrote to the disc since most discs are DVD-R, not DVD-RW

Comment: This answer makes little sense.  The two statements you make contradict one another.